# What to do when obj doesn't load properly in blender

Tags: 3d, blender

A few days ago I installed Blender on my computer and after installing every time I want to open an obj in it, it doesn't load properly. Here are some examples: http://i.xp.io/2p7kTkPC.png, http://i.xp.io/2p7tzMMv.png

I first thought it was the problem in my obj. Then I tried to open it with 3D viewer, and it loads properly. Here is an example of it: http://i.xp.io/2p7n9eMJ.png

This is a mega annoying problem that I am facing from a few days. Please help.

My pc specs: OS is Windows 10, Core 2 duo, Graphics card is Nvidia GeForce GT220 1GB.

Please help!

Comment: Best to ask on https://blender.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that your specs are enough for that. How much RAM does your PC have? The performance of the processor also looks insufficient. My i5 and 16GB of RAM sometimes fail to load 3D models into Blender (especially high-poly ones from [Artec](https://www.artec3d.com/3d-software/artec-studio) software).
I'd recommend upgrading your machine or try to load only low-poly models